# Can I customize the firebase OTP digits (default 6 to 4)?

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, sms, firebase-authentication

In my app, I'm using 4 digit OTP verification service. Now I'm trying to add Firebase phone number authentication method as my fallback method. Firebase OTP gives me 6 digits but I do not want to change my existing UI. How can I customize this?

Comment: Hey, did you find a way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

*firebaser here*

There is currently no way to change the length of the verification code that Firebase uses. I recommend that you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

If you don't want to depend on whether/when Firebase may add this, you can [implement your own identity provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth), where you have full control over its operation, including the password strength requirements.

Comment: Is this feature added in these 2 years?

Comment: Nope. I added a section to my answer on how you can accomplish the requirement today.