# How can i set the limit for firebase OTP digits like 6 to 4?

Tags: android, firebase

I am using 4 digit OTP verification in-my application. Firebase OTP gives me 6 digits but I want to 4 digits OTP. How can I set OTP digits limits?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141010/can-i-customize-the-firebase-otp-digits-default-6-to-4 Check here

Comment: In my experience there is no way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (August 1, 2019), there is no way to do this.

A lot of people have filed a request for this feature. A Googler gave [this response](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/YjYrgErWEK0) on Google groups in 2017.

> Thanks for the request! We don't have plans in the short-term to
>   support 4-digit codes but I can see why it might be a popular choice
>   for some apps and we'll look into supporting the use case in the
>   future. Just as a heads up, the Firebase support channel
>   (https://firebase.google.com/support/) is a great way to file feature
>   requests.

**ADDENDUM:** To file your own request or report a bug on anything Google-related, hit [this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

I hope this helps. Merry coding!